# Create folders at same time in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to create a number of folders with the same name but with a number at the end.

User should write a number and the script should create these numbers of folders. I don't know how to link the number and the number os folders.

Here is my script

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "(1617S2)" A.C.B.S
pwd
date
NOM="A.C.B.S"
echo $NOM
echo -n "Introduce el numero de carpetas que quieras :"
read x
if (($x<=10)); then
echo "Son $x carpetas"
else (($ <10))
echo -n "El número de carpetas tiene que ser entre 1 i 10 :"
read x2
echo "Son $x2 carpetas"
fi
cd ..
cd /var
sudo mkdir carpetaprincipal
cd ..
cd /var/carpetaprincipal
sudo mkdir carpeta {1..10}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `seq` with `xargs` to iterate and create the number of folders chosen for the input:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "(1617S2)" A.C.B.S
pwd ; date
NOM="A.C.B.S" ; echo $NOM

function makeFolders () {
    echo -n "Introduce el numero de carpetas que quieras :"
    read -r x

    if [[ "$x" -lt 11 ]] && [[ "$x" -gt 0 ]]; then
        echo "Son $x carpetas"

        cd ../var || exit
        mkdir carpetaprincipal

        cd carpetaprincipal || exit
        seq "$x" | xargs -I{} mkdir carpeta_{} 
    fi

    if [[ "$x" -lt 1 ]] || [[ "$x" -gt 10 ]]; then
        echo "El número de carpetas tiene que ser entre 1 i 10!"
        makeFolders # you could optionally exit 1 here
    fi
}

makeFolders
```

There were some other issues with your script, mainly the logic didn't make sense. If you put in more than 10 or less than 1 then the script still allowed the user to create folders which are above are below  what is supposed to be allowed. Putting those methods within in a function also allows you to return to the input line if there is an error. Also, `read` should include `-r`, otherwise it has the potential to mangle backslashes.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really usefull :)

Answer (score 0):

To do multiple `mkdir` while looping a variable number of times:

```
x2=4
i=1
while [ "$i" -le "$x2" ]
  do
    sudo mkdir carpeta$1
    i=$(($i + 1))
done
```

Comment: If you're going to use brace expansion, use it in the way it is primarily intended: `sudo mkdir carpeta{1..10}`.

Comment: Thanks for helping!